# Android: How to traverse through rows in a TableLayout and change checked state of checkbox using an alert dialog button

Tags: android

I have a tablelayout xml file that show elements from sqlite database into table format. What i want is to be able to have an alert dialog or a popup such that when i click on a button it changes the chechbox checked state to be true for that particular row. 
Here is my xml file (events.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:background="#EA6D11">

     <TableRow  
        android:id="@+id/table_row"
        android:background="#B18C58"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">

      <!-- Column 1 -->
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/eventId"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="5dip"       
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:textAllCaps="true"
         android:textColor="#00FF00"
         android:layout_margin="1dip"
         android:layout_weight="0.5"
         android:text="Column 0.5" />       

      <!-- Column 2 -->
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/eventName"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="5dip"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:textAllCaps="true"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:layout_margin="4dip"
         android:layout_weight="0.8"
         android:text="Column 2" />  

      <!-- Column 3 -->
      <TextView
         android:id="@+id/eventRecordName"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="5dip"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:textAllCaps="true"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:layout_margin="4dip"
         android:layout_weight="0.8"
         android:text="Column 3" />
    <!-- Column 4 -->   
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox"/>
        </TableRow> 

</TableLayout>
```

This is what i implemented in my activity class.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dbAdapter = new dbHelperAdapter(this); 
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);       
    Cursor eventListCursor = dbAdapter.fetchAllEvents();
    startManagingCursor(eventListCursor);        
    String[] from = new String[] {dbHelperAdapter.EVENT_ID, dbHelperAdapter.EVENT_NAME, dbHelperAdapter.EVENT_rNAME};
    int[] target = new int[]{R.id.eventId, R.id.eventName, R.id.eventRecordName};
    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.event_row_def, eventListCursor, from, target);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title);
    setListAdapter(cursorAdapter); 
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title);
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            lv.requestFocus();
            showPopup();
            return true;
        }

    });
}
```

This the showPopup() method.

```
        public void showPopup(){
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("EVENT");
        alert.setMessage("RollCall");       
        alert.setPositiveButton("MARK-EVENT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        @Override    
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
          //change checkbox checked state = true once clicked and move to next row
        }

    });

        alert.setNeutralButton("CLOSE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //require some actiion here once button is clicked
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

Thanks in advance for any thoughts deemed right for this implementation.

Comment: What particular row? Your current row just starts an `AlertDialog` after the `onCreate` method finishes.

Comment: Am new to android and i want to have 4 columns one showing the event, the other the eventName, then the eventRecord and the checkbox. But what i want is to be able to change the checked state from my screen for a particular event from an alert dialog...ie the dialog should start from the 1st line of my view on screen and once i tap MARK-EVENT button on the dialog it changes the state to true and moves to next element view ie row of my listing from the screen....thanks

Comment: So you want to popup the `AlertDialog` for each row in the `TableLayout` without any user interaction?

Comment: there's is a user interaction of course...i want if a long click is done any where on the screen from that activity an AlertDialog pops up and once the user clicks MARK-EVENT the checkBox of that event is changed to true and marked on the screen and the AlertDialog shifts to the next event....Sori i forgot to mention that the AlertDialog has TextView which changes with the eventName as we traverse through elements so that the user is able to know which event is being marked....thanks forgive for being a beginer

Comment: First to popup the dialog set a `OnItemLongClickListener` on the `ListView`. In that listener you'll have all the data required to identify the row so you could populate the dialog. To properly check the `CheckBox` from the list's row when the user marks the event, you'll need to use a custom adapter(search for a tutorial or other questions here) for the `ListView`. This is what you need to do what you want.

Comment: i want to set OnLongClicklistener on the Listview...meaning once one longclicks anywhere in the listview it shud popup a dialog but that has failed me as i get 10-24 00:34:54.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1117): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 10-24 00:34:54.805: E/AndroidRuntime(1117): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jypteroigne.DAMoSys.android/com.jypteroigne.DAMoSys.android.StudentListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException in my logcat

Comment: i hav edited the activity class u can hav a look at it........thanks

Comment: Se the `OnItemLongClickListener` on the `**ListView**`. In there using `Cursor data = (Cursor) parent.getItem(position);`(parent is the `AdapterView` parameter). Then using a custom adapter set the `CheckBox`.

Comment: I have tried to set **OnItemLongClickListener** on the **ListView** but nothing happens when i click....check my edited Activity class....thanks

Comment: Set the `CheckBox`  to be non focusable `android:focusable="false"`.